# How to determine which Activity launched current Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Without using an Intent and passing an extra parameter, is it possible to determine which Activity launched the current Activity?

Comment: Have you considered checking the top Acitivity on the backstack?It's not foolproof, but it can give you a general idea of where your Activity came from.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @loadedion .  Could you please point me in the direction / link  on how to do that?

Comment: You could use the `ActivityManager#getAppTasks()` method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getAppTasks() and try something like: 

`ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskList = manager.getAppTasks();
taskList.get(1).topActivity.getClassName();`

However, this approach might require extra app permissions

Comment: just go with Intents & life is good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two approaches to do.

1. **the common one**

use `startActivityForResult` in your calling activity to start the activity. Here I use `ActivityCompat` for backward compatibility.

```
ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(this, new Intent(this, MyActivity.class), 0, null);
```

Then in the callee activity, you can use the following code to detect the calling activity.

```
    if (getCallingActivity() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, getCallingActivity().getClassName());
    }
```

**NOTE**
In the calling activity, you don't have to implement `onActivityResult` if you don't need transfer data from callee activity.

2. **the deprecated one**

use the system's back stack to get the recent tasks. But it won't work after API 21, it's deprecated after API 21.

declare the necessary permission in the mainifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Then in your callee activity

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo taskInfo : activityManager.getRecentTasks(1, 0)) {
        Log.d(TAG, taskInfo.baseIntent.getComponent().getClassName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that crosses my mind is a HashMap with "lastActivity" "Activity" key and value.
It would be static so you can update it on every Activity incantation.
Or to save it as a SharedPreferences but that is the same as HashMap ...
Hope it helped, best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You Application class allows setting an `ActivityLifecycleListener`. Whenever a new activity touches `onCreate()` you can push the stuff like activities `toString()` or `getClass().getSimpleName()` on a stack of Strings, then use it to identify it.